# ImportError: No module named requests when requests exists

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have a program that use cgi to interface with a website. It works when I run the program as a script works, however, when I tried to connect it with the website interface, I get the following error in the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/revealMessage.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tweepy.api import API
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tweepy.binder import bind_api
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 11, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
[Mon Apr 24 01:49:50.997808 2017] [cgid:error] [pid 1593:tid 139798939764480] [client 127.0.0.1:56852] End of script output before headers: revealMessage.py, referer: http://localhost/hidden.html
```

I understand that the very last error is likely to do with how I'm using headers in the program, but I do not understand why tweepy can't import requests. It is a module that I have installed. What could be making this happen?

Comment: if you installed it with sudo, it "may" be caused by permission problems. Also, try checking the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: installed tweepy or requests? Should I just chmod 755 them?

Comment: requests, try `sudo chmod -R ugo+rX` on your site-packages

Comment: How did `requests` get installed?

Comment: I don't remember to be honest. I've not had a problem with it until now, but I assume sudo pip install

Comment: chmod like you said didn't work btw @richmondwang Wondering if it might be something to do with my cgi

Comment: does `requests` exist if you `find /usr/local/lib/python2.7 | grep requests` ?

Comment: @jmunsch Yep that finds the packages. I've just echoed PYTHONPATH and there's nothing there. This hasn't been a problem before though. But I'm guessing could be the source of using an odd import with a web app. What kind of thing would I set it to?

Comment: are you using a virtualenv? can you elaborate what you mean by website interface? maybe `cp -R ./requests/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` so `binder.py` can find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can install in a specific location, after use PYTHONPATH as environment variable :

```
pip3 install --target=<Your_Module_Path> <Your_Module> 
export PYTHONPATH=<Your_Module_Path>
```

**example** :

- Installation

  > ```
  > pip3 install --target=/usr/local/python3/module requests 
  > export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/python3/module
  > ```
- Check

  > ```
  > python3
  > Python 3.9.1 (default, Sep 17 2023, 22:52:11)
  > [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)] on linux
  > Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  > >>> import requests
  > >>> exit()
  > ```